# Numbering rows based on unique combinations of multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I have a data set in this style of format:

```
Treatments         Replicates           Value      Id
1                  1                    ###        NA
1                  1                    ###        NA
1                  1                    ###        NA
1                  2                    ###        NA
1                  2                    ###        NA
1                  2                    ###        NA
2                  1                    ###        NA
2                  1                    ###        NA
2                  1                    ###        NA
2                  2                    ###        NA
2                  2                    ###        NA
2                  2                    ###        NA
```

I am trying to code for R to fill in the 'id' column by numbering the rows for each unique combination of columns 'Treatments' and 'Replicates'.

The end result would be like:

```
Treatments         Replicates           Value      Id
1                  1                    ###        1
1                  1                    ###        2
1                  1                    ###        3
1                  2                    ###        1
1                  2                    ###        2
1                  2                    ###        3
2                  1                    ###        1
2                  1                    ###        2
2                  1                    ###        3
2                  2                    ###        1
2                  2                    ###        2
2                  2                    ###        3
```

This is a simplified data set. There are unequal numbers of each unique combination so the code will have to work down the dataframe somehow.

Thank you

Additional:

Is there a way to have the Id be a count of unique combinations? with a resulting df like:

```
Treatments         Replicates           Value      Id
1                  1                    ###        1
1                  1                    ###        1
1                  1                    ###        1
1                  2                    ###        2
1                  2                    ###        2
1                  2                    ###        2
2                  1                    ###        3
2                  1                    ###        3
2                  1                    ###        3
2                  2                    ###        4
2                  2                    ###        4
2                  2                    ###        4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rowid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
df1$Id <- with(df1, rowid(Treatments, Replicates))
```

Or using `data.table` syntax

```
setDT(df1)[, Id := rowid(Treatments, Replicates))]
```

If we need the group id, use `.GRP`

```
setDT(df1)[, Id := .GRP, .(Treatments, Replicates)]
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(Treatments, Replicates) %>% 
    mutate(Id = row_number())
```

To get the group indices, in the devel version

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(Treatments, Replicates) %>% 
  mutate(Id = cur_group_id())
```

Or in the current `dplyr` version

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(Id = group_indices(., Treatments, Replicates))
```

---

In `base R`, this can be done using `ave`

```
df1$Id <- with(df1, ave(seq_along(Treatments), Treatments,
             Replicates, FUN = seq_along))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Treatments = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Replicates = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Value = c(4L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 25L, 39L, 43L, 24L, 
12L, 9L, 4L, 2L), Id = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: thank you, is there a small adjustment to the code in order to change the id column counting to be the same number for Treatment and Replicate combinations?    so instead the Id column running down as "123123123..." it would be "111222333..." for the different combinations?

Comment: @JarrodVerSteeg updated the post.  I didn't see your updated comment